# Assigning multiple types to non-terminals in bison

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, yacc

I am trying to assign multiple data types to the non-terminal number and on googling I found this : [Assigning multiple data types to a non-terminal in yacc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905819/assigning-multiple-data-types-to-a-non-terminal-in-yacc) .
However this syntax does not seem to be working for me as on running it I get the following error :

```
new11.y:53.54-55: $3 of `initialization' has no declared type
new11.y:57.81-82: $5 of `increment' has no declared type
new11.y:70.33-34: $4 of `ifelse' has no declared type
```

Here is my code:

```
  %union{
    int ival;
    float fval;
    char *sval;
}

// define the terminal symbol token types
%token <ival> INTEGER
%token <fval> FLOAT
%token <sval> BLOCK
%token <sval> GOTO
%token PRINT IF ELSE RETURN
%token LESSTHAN LESSTHANEQUALTO GREATERTHAN GREATERTHANEQUALTO EQUALTO
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV
%token <sval> IDENTIFIER 
%type <sval> comparison

%%
//grammar which bison will parse

start:
    block statements { ; }
    | start block statements { ; }
    ;

block:
    BLOCK { cout<<"Block : "<<$1<<endl; }
    ;

number:
    INTEGER { $<ival>$=$1 }
    | FLOAT { $<fval>$=$1 }
    ;

initialization:
    IDENTIFIER EQUALTO number { cout<<$1<<" = "<<$3<<endl; }
    ;

increment:
    IDENTIFIER EQUALTO IDENTIFIER ADD number { cout <<$1<<" = "<<$3<<" + "<<$5<<endl; }
    ;

goto:
    GOTO { cout<<"GOTO : "<<$1<<endl; }
    ;

printing:
    PRINT { cout<<"printf(...)"<<endl; }
    ;

ifelse:
    IF IDENTIFIER comparison number GOTO ELSE GOTO
    { cout <<"if "<<$2<<$3<<$4<<", "<<$5<<",else, "<<$7<<endl; }
    ;

comparison:
    LESSTHAN { $$="<"; }
    | LESSTHANEQUALTO { $$="<=" }
    | GREATERTHAN { $$=">" }
    | GREATERTHANEQUALTO { $$=">=" }
    ;

statement:
    initialization
    | printing
    | goto
    | increment
    | ifelse
    | RETURN
    ;

statements:
    statements statement 
    | statement
    ;

%%

main() {
    // open a file handle to a particular file:
    FILE *myfile = fopen("test.cfg", "r");
    // make sure it is valid:
    if (!myfile) {
        cout << "I can't open a.snazzle.file!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // set flex to read from it instead of defaulting to STDIN:
    yyin = myfile;
    // parse through the input until there is no more:
    do {
        yyparse();
    } while (!feof(yyin));
}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    cout << "EEK, parse error!  Message: " << s << endl;
    // might as well halt now:
    exit(-1);
}
```

Where am I going wrong here? Did I not use the syntax right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is fairly clear. Your non-terminal `initialization` has `$3` of `number` and `number` needs a `%type` declaration. `$5` of `increment` and `$4` of `ifelse` is also `number`, so it is the same problem three times.

You probably need to create a discriminated union to represent either an integer or a float, and use that union in the the `%union`:

```
struct Number
{
    enum { INTEGER, FLOAT } type;
    union
    {
        float fval;
        int   ival;
    };
};
```

and then:

```
%union
{
    char *sval;
    Number nval;
};
```

---

This grammar compiles in Bison — there's probably code work to do at the C++ level.  If anonymous unions aren't in C++, add a name for the union inside `struct Number`.  Your tokenizer will need to set both the `type` and either `ival` or `fval` fields of the `struct Number`.  You can't write plain `main()` in C++; you must prefix it with `int`.

```
%{
struct Number
{
    enum { INTEGER, FLOAT } type;
    union
    {
        float fval;
        int   ival;
    };
};
%}

%union
{
    Number nval;
    char  *sval;
}

// define the terminal symbol token types
%token <nval> INTEGER
%token <nval> FLOAT
%token <sval> BLOCK
%token <sval> GOTO
%token PRINT IF ELSE RETURN
%token LESSTHAN LESSTHANEQUALTO GREATERTHAN GREATERTHANEQUALTO EQUALTO
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV
%token <sval> IDENTIFIER 
%type <sval> comparison
%type <nval> number

%%
//grammar which bison will parse

start:
    block statements { ; }
    | start block statements { ; }
    ;

block:
    BLOCK { cout<<"Block : "<<$1<<endl; }
    ;

number:
    INTEGER { $$=$1 }
    | FLOAT { $$=$1 }
    ;

initialization:
    IDENTIFIER EQUALTO number { cout<<$1<<" = "<<$3<<endl; }
    ;

increment:
    IDENTIFIER EQUALTO IDENTIFIER ADD number { cout <<$1<<" = "<<$3<<" + "<<$5<<endl; }
    ;

goto:
    GOTO { cout<<"GOTO : "<<$1<<endl; }
    ;

printing:
    PRINT { cout<<"printf(...)"<<endl; }
    ;

ifelse:
    IF IDENTIFIER comparison number GOTO ELSE GOTO
    { cout <<"if "<<$2<<$3<<$4<<", "<<$5<<",else, "<<$7<<endl; }
    ;

comparison:
    LESSTHAN { $$="<"; }
    | LESSTHANEQUALTO { $$="<=" }
    | GREATERTHAN { $$=">" }
    | GREATERTHANEQUALTO { $$=">=" }
    ;

statement:
    initialization
    | printing
    | goto
    | increment
    | ifelse
    | RETURN
    ;

statements:
    statements statement 
    | statement
    ;

%%

int main() {
    // open a file handle to a particular file:
    FILE *myfile = fopen("test.cfg", "r");
    // make sure it is valid:
    if (!myfile) {
        cout << "I can't open a.snazzle.file!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // set flex to read from it instead of defaulting to STDIN:
    yyin = myfile;
    // parse through the input until there is no more:
    do {
        yyparse();
    } while (!feof(yyin));
}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    cout << "EEK, parse error!  Message: " << s << endl;
    // might as well halt now:
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work for me.  I am wondering how can the non-terminal number with Number type can be printed out in $5 of increment ?   Also do these INTEGER { $$=$1 }
    | FLOAT { $$=$1 } need ";" ?

Comment: For Bison, the missing semicolons don't matter — for the C++ compiler, they probably do (so add them).  Your "it does not work for me" comment is unanswerable; it does (or did) work for me.  You'd have to ask a new question with your MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and if I see it, or you add a comment here, I can look at it.  As to the printing out, you'd need some conditional code: `cout << $1 << " = " << $3 << " + "; if ($5.type == INTEGER) cout << $5.ival; else cout << $5.fval; cout << endl;` or thereabouts.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.